# Spring MVC without HTTP requests

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I need to create a system oriented around Methods where providers can register for the Methods they handle and consumers can do two things (for now) - either get Metadata for a method or execute it. I'm considering creating a REST style architecture where methods are resources with unique URIs and an interface consisting of two methods - getMetadata and Execute.

I'll need to have an equivalent of @RequestMapping so that the provider that handles specific methods can be located by the central dispatcher. As a result the provider will return either Model or Metadata object.

This looks pretty similar to Spring MVC but I don't want to expose and consume my resources(methods) over the web and use http as this will incur unnecessary overhead. Instead I want to use it like a standard java API where java methods are called and java objects are transferred.
I can do that by writing my own equivalent of @RequestMapping and Dispatcher logic but I was wondering if there's a better way to do this with Spring. Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Kostadin

Comment: Do you mean APIs accessed locally within the JVM, or over the network just not using HTTP?

Comment: The former - API accessed within the JVM.

Comment: So Kostadin did you ever try out NetKernel, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you want to do using REST and everything will have a unique URI but **not** over `HTTP`?? Sounds like you are looking for RMI or something similar... Chech [Burlap](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/protocols/burlap.xtp) or [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/) both of them has excellent support from spring.

Comment: Yes, because the system consist of dynamic methods which could be provided by different parties I thought of using URIs to identify and locate the methods. But I want everything to stay inside the JVM and not go over HTTP.

Comment: REST itself says nothing about HTTP - it's perfectly viable to implement REST concepts over pretty much any protocol, it just so happens that a lot of people are doing it over HTTP.  Just because he doesn't use HTTP doesn't make it RMI.

Comment: @Gandalf Right. Is there currently any other implementation of REST other than over HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

There's software out there called [NetKernel](http://www.1060research.com/netkernel/) that might interest you.  Its literature says that it is an implementation of Resource-Oriented Computing.  It looks like it rigorously separates its logical computing model from the physical details.  It's RESTful, defining a resource model, a limited set of verbs, and a naming scheme.  Implemented in Java.  Comes with HTTP and other transports built in.

It doesn't have a Java in-process transport, but you could probably write one for it pretty easily.

Hmm...if you never need to process requests from out-of-process sources, it's probably overkill for you, but maybe it will show you some useful patterns.

Comment: This looks very similar to what I need. I'll take a closer look at it even though it doesn't support in-process transport that I need. Thanks!